# touchscreen, touch-screen, touch screen? Merriam-Webster and Oxford disagree

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, compounds, spacing

I have searched but cannot find a definite answer on the correct to write "touch screen". Merriam-Webster says [touch screen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touchscreen). Oxford says [touchscreen](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/touchscreen?q=touch%20screen). And random people around the internet say "touch-screen".

What is the most correct and professional way to write *touchscreen* in the following sentence?

> We recommend using your touchscreen device instead of a mouse to draw a silly face in the box below.

Comment: Usage evidence offered by Google Books shows that "touch screen" is the more common, but they are all used:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=touchscreen%2Ctouch+screen%2Ctouch-screen&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctouchscreen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctouch%20screen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctouch%20-%20screen%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

I will be very surprised if *touchscreen* doesn't end up being closed up as one word (with no hyphen) in the vast majority of dictionaries within the next 25 years.

The Ngram chart for *touch screen* (blue line) versus *touchscreen* (red line) for the years 1970–2008 shows a persistent lead for the former, but that is before touchscreens on laptops became a standard feature:

[image]

(Note, however, that the results are artificially high for *touch screen* because—owing to a design decision in how to deal with hyphens—Ngram treats all instances of *touch-screen* as instances of *touch screen*.)

At the (U.S.) computer magazines where I have worked, our house style switched from *touch screen* to *touchscreen* at some point between 2005 and 2010, if I recall correctly. I'll check and see if I can nail the date down a bit more securely.

**UPDATE:** I found a word list from January 2009 that showed our computer magazines as still adhering to *touch screen* for the noun and *touch-screen* for the adjective at that date—but I'm sure that by 2012 we had shifted to *touchscreen* as house style.

Comment: Why not add "touch-screen" to your Ngram?

Comment: @Josh61: Ngram can't distinguish between line-break hyphens and "hard" hyphens, so it can't plot hyphenated words. Instead, it defaults to treating them as separate words, which means that all instances of _touch-screen_ in the Google Books database are added to the numbers for _touch screen_ in the chart above.

Comment: Please have a look at my link.

Comment: @Josh61: Yeah...what you have there is a line for "touch [minus] screen," which I have no idea how to interpret, but which doesn't yield any data points in the 'Search in Google Boooks' links beneath the graph. On the other hand, if you click one of the date links for _touch screen_ there—say, '2004–2005'—you'll see instances of _touch-screen_ listed as though they were matches for _touch screen_. Both hyphens and apostrophe freak out Ngram, so you just have to avoid asking for graphs of words and phrases that contain them.

Comment: What a disgusting, hygienically questionable, word.